# How do I switch back and forth between JPanels?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

I am switching JPanels perfectly fine except I cannot switch back to a JPanel that I have already visited. I have three buttons to switch between three JPanels.
My buttons look like this:

```
content.removeAll();
content.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
content.validate();
repaint();
```

I can go to the panels fine, but I can't then return to previously visited panels. I would like to be able to go back to those panels, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't tear down your gui like that. Use a `CardLayout`

Comment: [How to use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)